# Way to pause the Android Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I do a lot of development on my laptop, and I use various Android Emulators to do it.  When running, the emulator frequently takes up a large amount of my CPU, and consequently decreases my laptop's battery life significantly.

Is there a way to temporarily pause the emulator, or at least shut down whatever it is that's consuming all the unnecessary cpu?

I know that with sdk r9 and later I can snapshot the emulator and quit/restart it fairly quickly, but I'm hoping for something even less invasive to my work flow than that.

Comment: In case you have actual device, and your development required SDK is less than your device, try to use the device instead of emulator. Why? 1. It is fast 2. You will get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**In Linux you can stop the process by**

```
$ killall --signal STOP emulator
```

or

```
$ killall --signal STOP emulator64-arm
```

**At a later time continue by**

```
$ killall --signal CONT emulator
```

or

```
$ killall --signal CONT emulator64-arm
```

**Gotcha**: If you update Eclipse, make sure the emulator is not stopped when restarting eclipse.  Eclipse will stall when loading, waiting for the stopped emulator to continue.

Comment: Yeah I was just experimenting with that. Seems to work well so far.

Answer (score 6):

The newest version of adt supports emulator snapshots, meaning you can just close the emulator and bring it back to where it was quickly. So to solve your problem simply close your emulator and restore it when you need it.

Check snapshot enabled when creating your avd:
[image: Check snapshot enabled when creating your avd]

Ensure launch and save snapshot are checked when launching:

[image: Ensure launch and save snapshot are checked when launching]

Comment: Under current emulation options you can only choose one of "Snapshot", "Use Host GPU".  IE you cannot make use of your host machine's GPU at the same time as using emulator snapshots.

Answer (score 1):

For a cross-platform solution, this should pause and then resume execution of the emulator:

```
$ telnet localhost 5554  
> avd stop  
> avd start
```

Comment: This does not work for me ( running a TV emu in 2020). Getting error: avd stop
allows you to control (e.g. start/stop) the execution of the virtual device

available sub-commands:
    name             query virtual device name

KO:  bad sub-command

Answer (score 0):

## On Mac OSX

Using Activity Monitor, find the Process ID # (PID) for your emulator.

[image: PID number of emulator]

### To Stop

In Terminal telnet to your emulator:

```
telnet localhost 5554
```

Stop the emulator

```
avd stop
```

In another Terminal window, stop (pause) the process (19636 is an example PID, you'll need the particular PID for your emulator from Activity Monitor):

```
kill -STOP 19636
```

### To Restart

To restart emulator, from the telnet connection to emulator:

```
avd start
```

Then finally continue the process from the OSX Terminal:

```
kill -CONT 19636
```

I found that simply doing kill -STOP/CONT would not allow the emulator to come back to life when trying to restart.  After continuing the process, the emulator would remain frozen, although it's CPU usage returned to normal.

Stopping the emulator via telnet, then stopping the process then reversing these steps to restart, seemed to work flawlessly.